# JsonConvert.SerializeObject vs json_encode

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I am Converting asp.net c# application into php i am facing problem with json encode like i have to encode one datetime field like created date into php so i am using simply

```
$arr=array('OrderDate'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
echo `json_encode($arr);`
//output => {"OrderDate": "2017-03-22 06:21:28"}
```

same thing in asp.net

```
Order objOrder= new Order();
objOrder.OrderDate = SystemTime.Now();
JsonConvert.SerializeObject($objOrder);
```

returns

```
{"OrderDate": "2017-03-22T10:40:17.313313+05:30"}
```

i wanted to exactly same output like asp.net using php json_encode() how do i achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr=array('OrderDate'=>date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP'));
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$arr=array('OrderDate'=>date('Y-m-dTH:i:s.uP'));
echo `json_encode($arr);`
```

or

```
$arr=array('OrderDate'=>date('c'));
echo `json_encode($arr);`
```

I found [php date format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).